# Truth Value for series in ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

The data is a short example. I will have about 11 different 'if these 2 conditions are True return 'this text' ' and will apply it to 3k rows.  i wrote out the column names as variables to avoid typing the column names for each condition.

i keep getting a ValueError, truth value in ambiguous.  All the post i have seen talk about using bitwise & and separating each test with parenthesis. which i do. but it still errors. i tried including the column fully referenced but still errors on ValueError. if i take out 'self' from function i get TypeError. Not sure how to figure this one out.

```
data = [ [3.5, 6], [-4,-8],[4,1] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['line','value'])

l = df['line']
v = df['value']

def errortype(self):
   if (l >=0) & (v > l):
      return 'error1'
   elif (l < 0) & (v < l):
      return 'error2'

df['test']= df.apply(errortype, axis=1)
```

Comment: You need `all` or `any` in your if statements.  You have a series l and you check to see if l is >= 0.  Well, what if part of L were negative and part of L is positive.  The the if statement is ambiguious.  Do you want to check to see if `any` part of l is negative or if `all` of l is negative?  Use `any` or `all`.

Comment: isn't this going row by row. i thought using the df.apply()  would use it on each row. so for row 1 its. 'if 3.5>=0 & 6 > 3.5" return 'error1'

Comment: L is still a series in your global.  Yes, df. is going by row, but l is not.

Comment: still not 100% sure. i thought & means both need to be True for the entire condition to be true. Or in Pandas its just a way of connecting conditions? If i need both conditions to be true then how would i rewrite the If statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
data = [ [3.5, 6], [-4,-8],[4,1] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['line','value'])


#l = df['line']  do not need this line
#v = df['value']  do not need this line

def errortype(row):
#     print(row)
    if (row['line'] >=0) & (row['value'] > row['line']):
        return 'error1'
    elif (row['line'] < 0) & (row['value'] < row['line']):
        return 'error2'

df['test']= df.apply(errortype, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   line  value    test
0   3.5      6  error1
1  -4.0     -8  error2
2   4.0      1    None
```

---

However, a better vectorized way is to use `np.select`

```
cond1 = (df['line'] >= 0) & (df['value'] > df['line'])
cond2 = (df['line'] < 0) & (df['value'] < df['line'])

df['test'] = np.select([cond1,cond2],['error1','error2'],np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   line  value    test
0   3.5      6  error1
1  -4.0     -8  error2
2   4.0      1     nan
```

Comment: thanks scott, this works. But still had some questions. anyway I can use the variables l and v or because i am using 'row' i need to specify the full column name?  Also, your original response mentioned using all/any, how would that look?

Comment: For give me I am not a computer science person, but when you `l = df['line']` you are taking the series in df dataframe and assigned it to `l`.   Do a print(l) inside your function and watch what happens.  You are not "referencing" df['line'] with l.  Which is what you think.  Ignore the all or any comment, you don't need this because you are going row by row.

Comment: The second method works without iterating because pandas does something called intrinsic data alignement, meaning that almost all operations done in pandas will align  (match) the data on the index and column headers.